# Acer Aspire wifi on Broadcom b43 not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, hardware, b43

```
ck, including userspace.
[   79.694480] [drm] Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
[   79.694486] [drm] drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue.
[   79.694491] [drm] The gpu crash dump is required to analyze gpu hangs, so please always attach it.
[   79.696049] i915: render error detected, EIR: 0x00000010
[   79.696049] i915: page table error
[   79.696049] i915:   PGTBL_ER: 0x00000040
[   79.696049] [drm:i915_report_and_clear_eir] *ERROR* EIR stuck: 0x00000010, masking
[   79.696049] i915: render error detected, EIR: 0x00000010
[   79.696049] i915: page table error
[   79.696049] i915:   PGTBL_ER: 0x00000040
[   93.983517] perf samples too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[  224.229431] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  228.207777] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  232.725219] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[  232.725259] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  321.189010] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  322.831456] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[  337.015214] perf samples too long (5015 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
[  621.522143] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  623.359404] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[  623.494648] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  625.061363] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[  628.197679] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  630.025169] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[  634.650226] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  636.225712] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[ 3944.776711] systemd-hostnamed[3036]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[11869.496179] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[11869.630837] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1653
[11869.630853] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[11869.630864] usb 1-4: Product: DT 100 G2
[11869.630873] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Kingston
[11869.630882] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 001CC0EC32C7ACB04711A416
[11870.426563] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11870.426943] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[11870.427234] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[11872.390508] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access                               1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[11872.391226] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[11872.394226] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 30343168 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
[11872.398382] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[11872.398399] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 2f 00 00 00
[11872.405594] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[11872.415283]  sdb: sdb1
[11872.423367] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[11873.811057] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[11876.588315] systemd-hostnamed[4088]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[11924.556986] sdb: detected capacity change from 15535702016 to 0
[11926.962013] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[21782.745195] systemd-hostnamed[6196]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[29001.288243] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[35250.538247] systemd-hostnamed[6971]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[35650.320252] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[35650.454806] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1653
[35650.454823] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[35650.454834] usb 1-4: Product: DT 100 G2
[35650.454843] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Kingston
[35650.454852] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 001CC0EC32C7ACB04711A416
[35650.455797] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[35650.458679] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[35652.620950] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access                               1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[35652.621606] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[35652.623276] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 30343168 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
[35652.625025] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[35652.625040] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 2f 00 00 00
[35652.630580] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[35652.650596]  sdb: sdb1
[35652.656831] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[35653.343547] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[35657.330650] systemd-hostnamed[7931]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[35741.288976] sdb: detected capacity change from 15535702016 to 0
[35743.479897] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[42887.219643] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[42888.862132] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[42929.836687] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[42934.232127] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[42940.724508] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[42940.957311] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[42940.957536] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.075 seconds) done.
[42941.033293] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[42941.034755] PM: Entering mem sleep
[42941.034832] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[42941.035235] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[42941.039579] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[42941.508205] PM: suspend of devices complete after 473.133 msecs
[42941.524244] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.023 msecs
[42941.524590] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[42941.540277] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[42941.556124] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[42941.556207] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[42941.556289] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[42941.556371] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[42941.556638] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.386 msecs
[42941.556684] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[42941.556820] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[42941.558126] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[42941.660034] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[42941.660334] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[42941.660334] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S0_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[42941.660334] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[42941.660334] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[42941.660334] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[42941.660334] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[42941.559941] Initializing CPU#1
[42941.559941] Disabled fast string operations
[42941.672745] CPU1 is up
[42941.673369] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[42941.704473] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[42941.704560] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[42941.704644] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[42941.704729] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[42941.720125] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[42941.768244] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 94.678 msecs
[42941.768736] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.444 msecs
[42941.769273] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[42941.769751] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[42941.770087] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[42941.770431] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[42941.770759] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[42941.771637] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[42941.988170] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[42942.096071] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[42943.160086] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[42943.161290] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[42943.171201] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[42943.171660] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[42943.184350] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[42943.345619] PM: resume of devices complete after 1576.870 msecs
[42943.346031] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[42943.346036] Restarting tasks ... done.
[42943.356253] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[42944.594242] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[42944.609615] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[42954.633419] systemd-hostnamed[9287]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[43509.340446] perf samples too long (10049 > 10000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 12500
[48070.228293] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[48070.377138] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[48070.377410] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[48070.380294] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[48070.381755] PM: Entering mem sleep
[48070.381841] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[48070.382247] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[48070.404992] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[48070.876224] PM: suspend of devices complete after 494.139 msecs
[48070.892245] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.005 msecs
[48070.892590] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48070.908278] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48070.924125] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48070.924208] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48070.924289] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48070.924371] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48070.924637] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.385 msecs
[48070.924682] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[48070.924820] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[48070.926142] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48071.028038] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[48071.028272] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[48071.028272] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S0_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[48071.028272] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[48071.028272] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48071.028272] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[48071.028272] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[48070.927740] Initializing CPU#1
[48070.927740] Disabled fast string operations
[48071.040738] CPU1 is up
[48071.044324] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[48071.076476] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48071.076563] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48071.076647] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48071.076730] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48071.092135] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48071.140248] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 95.580 msecs
[48071.140746] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.449 msecs
[48071.144466] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[48071.144953] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[48071.145283] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[48071.145626] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[48071.145953] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[48071.146634] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48071.360130] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[48071.468082] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[48072.308066] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[48072.309321] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[48072.317527] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[48072.317952] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[48072.332158] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[48072.776241] PM: resume of devices complete after 1635.483 msecs
[48072.776712] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[48072.776717] Restarting tasks ... done.
[48072.807473] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[48073.997641] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[48074.013368] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[48096.023312] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[48096.130098] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[48096.130319] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[48096.133155] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[48096.134549] PM: Entering mem sleep
[48096.134623] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[48096.135034] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[48096.136224] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[48096.612218] PM: suspend of devices complete after 477.354 msecs
[48096.628246] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.012 msecs
[48096.628592] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48096.644279] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48096.660124] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48096.660207] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48096.660289] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48096.660371] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48096.660639] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.385 msecs
[48096.660683] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[48096.660821] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[48096.662105] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48096.764057] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[48096.764315] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[48096.764315] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S0_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[48096.764315] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[48096.764315] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48096.764315] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[48096.764315] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[48096.663703] Initializing CPU#1
[48096.663703] Disabled fast string operations
[48096.776756] CPU1 is up
[48096.777376] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[48096.808465] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48096.808552] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48096.808635] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48096.808720] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48096.824125] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48096.872244] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 94.531 msecs
[48096.872740] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.447 msecs
[48096.876461] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[48096.876948] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[48096.877279] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[48096.877622] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[48096.877949] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[48096.878631] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48097.092199] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[48097.196166] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[48098.036191] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[48098.037487] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[48098.053265] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[48098.053709] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[48098.068316] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[48098.095343] ACPI Error: [_T_0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20131115/dswload2-330)
[48098.095350] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20131115/psobject-222)
[48098.095362] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.WMID.WMBA] (Node f582e528), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20131115/psparse-536)
[48098.095391] ACPI Error: [_T_0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20131115/dswload2-330)
[48098.095397] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20131115/psobject-222)
[48098.095407] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.WMID.WMBA] (Node f582e528), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20131115/psparse-536)
[48098.095482] PM: resume of devices complete after 1222.734 msecs
[48098.095903] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[48098.095907] Restarting tasks ... done.
[48098.102021] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[48098.144522] ACPI: Marking method WMBA as Serialized because of AE_ALREADY_EXISTS error
[48099.382020] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[48099.397607] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[48121.146220] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[48121.254444] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[48121.254681] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[48121.257632] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[48121.259162] PM: Entering mem sleep
[48121.259232] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[48121.259658] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[48121.260998] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[48121.732217] PM: suspend of devices complete after 472.744 msecs
[48121.748244] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.010 msecs
[48121.748591] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48121.764280] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48121.780124] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48121.780207] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48121.780289] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48121.780371] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48121.780638] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.386 msecs
[48121.780683] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[48121.780820] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[48121.782102] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48121.884034] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[48121.884289] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[48121.884289] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S0_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[48121.884289] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[48121.884289] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48121.884289] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[48121.884289] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[48121.783808] Initializing CPU#1
[48121.783808] Disabled fast string operations
[48121.896724] CPU1 is up
[48121.897307] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[48121.928469] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48121.928556] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48121.928640] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48121.928724] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48121.944124] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48121.992243] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 94.566 msecs
[48121.992736] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.445 msecs
[48121.993410] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[48121.996436] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[48121.996790] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[48121.997112] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[48121.997438] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[48121.998124] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48122.212134] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[48122.316110] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[48123.156072] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[48123.157309] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[48123.171008] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[48123.171427] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[48123.184168] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[48123.344229] PM: resume of devices complete after 1351.480 msecs
[48123.344703] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[48123.344709] Restarting tasks ... done.
[48123.351304] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[48124.549841] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[48124.565564] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[48146.139175] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[48146.239021] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[48146.239320] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.005 seconds) done.
[48146.244878] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[48146.246422] PM: Entering mem sleep
[48146.246492] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[48146.246902] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[48146.247777] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[48146.724199] PM: suspend of devices complete after 477.466 msecs
[48146.740242] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.027 msecs
[48146.740589] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48146.756276] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48146.772125] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48146.772208] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48146.772289] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48146.772371] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[48146.772638] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.389 msecs
[48146.772683] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[48146.772819] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[48146.774105] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48146.876035] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[48146.876296] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[48146.876296] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S0_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[48146.876296] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[48146.876296] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[48146.876296] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[48146.876296] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[48146.775812] Initializing CPU#1
[48146.775812] Disabled fast string operations
[48146.888734] CPU1 is up
[48146.889351] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[48146.920468] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48146.920554] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48146.920639] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48146.920723] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48146.936124] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48146.984243] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 94.693 msecs
[48146.984734] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.443 msecs
[48146.988466] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[48146.988956] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[48146.989289] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[48146.989632] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[48146.989962] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[48146.990643] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[48147.204195] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[48147.308178] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[48148.372244] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[48148.373517] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[48148.388036] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[48148.388493] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[48148.404254] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[48148.572697] PM: resume of devices complete after 1587.951 msecs
[48148.573245] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[48148.573250] Restarting tasks ... done.
[48148.583644] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[48149.738976] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[48149.753614] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[48165.238769] systemd-hostnamed[13919]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[50106.558149] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[50106.706877] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[50106.707098] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[50106.709839] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[50106.711312] PM: Entering mem sleep
[50106.711393] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[50106.711804] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[50106.753205] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[50107.220194] PM: suspend of devices complete after 508.560 msecs
[50107.236273] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.063 msecs
[50107.252295] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[50107.268124] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[50107.268208] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[50107.268290] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[50107.268371] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[50107.268639] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.358 msecs
[50107.268685] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[50107.268821] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[50107.270118] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[50107.372035] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[50107.372281] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[50107.372281] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S0_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[50107.372281] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[50107.372281] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[50107.372281] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[50107.372281] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[50107.271833] Initializing CPU#1
[50107.271833] Disabled fast string operations
[50107.384690] CPU1 is up
[50107.385285] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[50107.416468] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[50107.416555] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[50107.416639] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[50107.416723] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[50107.432125] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[50107.480243] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 94.760 msecs
[50107.480734] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.442 msecs
[50107.484464] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[50107.484953] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[50107.485285] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[50107.485629] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[50107.485958] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
[50107.700220] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[50107.808112] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[50108.872083] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[50108.873373] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[50108.880577] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[50108.881045] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[50108.896741] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[50109.064235] PM: resume of devices complete after 1583.488 msecs
[50109.064642] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[50109.064647] Restarting tasks ... done.
[50109.077600] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[50110.258603] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[50110.273672] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[50125.981499] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up
[50125.981537] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[53882.643764] systemd-hostnamed[16002]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[54395.577133] systemd-hostnamed[16717]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[55564.003329] systemd-hostnamed[16778]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[56181.661477] systemd-hostnamed[17552]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[58766.434122] systemd-hostnamed[18475]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
administrator@administrator-Aspire-one:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary internet connection; ethernet, tether or however. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After it completes, reboot and let us hear your report.

If your wireless is still not working, check for clues:

```
dmesg | grep b43
rfkill list all
```

If it still isn't working, please try:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf 
sudo modprobe b43
```

It is working? If not,please let us see the same pastes as above so we may check for errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: I just did that today but with no avail.

What could be the problem

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: i will let you know again..

I re-added more when i edited again above initial post.

Comment: @chil555 nothing changed.

Comment: @chestertakau did you post the additional diagnostics I requested?

Comment: nothing changed. I am trying ndiswrapper but still the same.

Comment: We can't suggest a fix without the _dmesg_ and _rfkill_ listings I requested. Please help me help you.

Comment: I cannot post all dmesg on edited post. this means i will also need to post all rfkill listings again in another post ? anyway see my dmesg list and see if you can help me.
Thanks for your help .

Comment: 0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Please post both here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com Thanks.

Comment: see attached is the link to what you asked http://paste.ubuntu.com/8408605/

Comment: more here http://paste.ubuntu.com/8408632/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8453854/ is what you requested